# Cannot instantiate interface Spatie\Health\ResultStores\ResultStore

Tags: php, laravel, spatie-health

I need to use the `ResultStore` in my Laravel file. When I try to initialise it I get the following error:

> Cannot instantiate interface Spatie\Health\ResultStores\ResultStore

What am I missing?

```php
/**
 * Get health status
 */
public function getHealthStatus(): array
{
    $schema = [
        'label' => 'Healthy',
        'state' => 'healthy',
        'textClass' => 'white',
        'bgClass' => 'success'
    ];

    try {
        $latestResults = (new ResultStore())->latestResults();

        // health checks not found
        if (! $latestResults) {
            $schema['label'] = 'Progressing';
            $schema['state'] = 'progressing';
            $schema['textClass'] = 'white';
            $schema['bgClass'] = 'info';

            return $schema;
        }

        $failedChecks = collect($latestResults->storedCheckResults)->filter(function ($item) {
            return $item->status == 'failed';
        })->count();

        $warnChecks = collect($latestResults->storedCheckResults)->filter(function ($item) {
            return $item->status == 'warning';
        })->count();

        if ($warnChecks > 0) {
            $schema['label'] = 'Degraded';
            $schema['state'] = 'degraded';
            $schema['textClass'] = 'dark';
            $schema['bgClass'] = 'warning';
        }

        if ($failedChecks > 0) {
            $schema['label'] = 'Critical';
            $schema['state'] = 'critical';
            $schema['textClass'] = 'white';
            $schema['bgClass'] = 'danger';
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // ...
    }

    return $schema;
}
```

This function is called further down in my proect:

```php
/**
 * Get app content
 */
public function app(): array
{
    $stats = [];

    $stats['health_status'] = $this->getHealthStatus();

    return $stats;
}
```

Comment: Try `$latestResults = app(ExampleResultStore::class)->latestResults();` and see

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to instantiate an interface, and the error says that to you.
Instead you should ask the provider to get the concrete class bound to that interface for you.
Please replace:

```
$latestResults = (new ResultStore())->latestResults();
```

with:

```
$latestResults = app(ResultStore::class)->latestResults();
```